# How to sort the array

Tags: php, mysql

How to sort array by preserving key

```
 $arr = array(strong text
    'a' => array('date' => time() - 1000),
    'b' => array('date' => time() - 2000),
    'c' => array('date' => time() - 3000),
);
```

I want to sort according to the time().

Comment: What do you want to sort by?

Comment: according to the time() i want to short

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
   if($a["date"] == $b["date"]) return 0;

   return($a["date"] >  $b["date"]) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of PHP functions that sort arrays - you can see the overview here: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

As you want to neither by key nor value, but by some custom logic of yours, you need to use one of the functions starting with **u**. Ouf of those 3 functions, 2 can be used to sort by value: **usort** and **uasort**. The difference between them is that while the first one doesn't preserve the key-value associations, the second one does, which makes **uasort** the function you need.

**uasort** takes 2 parameters - an array to be sorted and a callback, that for 2 given elements should return **-1, 0 or 1** if the first element is **smaller, equal or larger** than the second.

In your case, this will work:

```
print_r($arr);

uasort($arr, function($e1, $e2) {
  if ($e1['date'] == $e2['date']) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($e1['date'] < $e2['date']) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($arr);
```

**Notice:** make sure you don't assign the result of uasort to your $arr - the return value of this function is not the sorted array, but a boolean saying if sorting succeeded.